# Redux Action is Firing but UI is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

The action is receiving the props and is logging them to console, but my component receiving these same props won't render on my UI. This is a React Native app.  This is a [link to the Repo](https://github.com/psychatelli/Redux-PleaseHelp)
All pages to review are in the src folder.

I followed [Buckies video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x3gitcwtAc&index=9&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBbSLZjvleMwldX8jGgXV6a) to get this going, so my code is almost exactly like his. The Only line of code I changed is my OnPress function. This is the only syntax I've tried that allowed the console to receive the props.  Also, in his video series, he creates two separate components.  I merged both components into one component so I have less code to past below. Been trying to get this to work all week:(

**MY ACTION CREATOR:**

```
import USER_SELECTED from './types';

export const selectUser = (user) => {
console.log("You clicked on user:", user.first);
return {
    type: USER_SELECTED,
    payload: user
   }
};
```

**MY ACTION REDUCER**

```
import USER_SELECTED from '../actions/types';

export default (state={}, action) => {

switch(action.type) {
  case USER_SELECTED:
    return action.payload;
    break;
}
return state;  
};
```

**MY COMPONENT**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../../actions';

class UserList extends Component {

    createListItems() {
        return this.props.users.map((user) => {
            return (    
                <View key={user.id}> 
                    <Button onPress={function(){return selectUser(user);}}>
                        <Text>{user.first} {user.last}</Text>
                        <Icon  style={styles.TextLight} name='arrow-forward' android="md-arrow-forward"/>
                    </Button>
                </View>
                );
            });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
        <View>

            {this.createListItems()}
            {/* ALL BUTTONS ARE MAPPED, AND DISPLAYED HERE */}

            <View> 
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20, margin: 10}}>First: {this.props.user.first} </Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 15, margin: 10}}>Last: {this.props.user.last} </Text>
                {/* THESE TEXT OBJECTS ARE NOT DISPLAYING THE PROPS WHEN THE BUTTON ABOVE IS CLICK.  IT ONLY SHOWS 
                IN THE CONSOLE.  */}
            </View>

        </View>
            );
    }
}

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            users: state.users,
            user: state.activeUser 
        };
    }

    function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators({ selectUser: selectUser }, dispatch)
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

**MY SCREEN**

```
  import UserDetails from '../../components/users/ActiveUser';

  class LCL extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <Container>
              {/* <ImageBackground source={launchscreenBg} style=
              {styles.imageContainer}>  */}
            <Header style={styles.MainContainer} hasTabs>
                <Left/>
                <Body>
                    <Title style={styles.title_font}>LCL</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right />
            </Header>

        <Content padder>
        <Text>
            This is the LCL shipments
        </Text>

            <UserList />

        </Content>
            <Footer_Nav navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
        </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default LCL
```

**MY INDEX.JS FILE WITHIN MY REDUCER FILE**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
//import keys from './keys_reducer';
import UserReducer from './LCL_reducer_data';
import AirReducer from './Air_reducer_data';
import ActiveUserReducer from './LCL_ActionReducer_active_user';



const AllReducers = combineReducers({

  users: UserReducer,
  AirList: AirReducer,
  activeUser: ActiveUserReducer,
    //keys: keys,
});

export default AllReducers;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not dispatching the action correctly, you are just running the action creator but it's not doing anything just returning an object (the actual action).

In order to fix this, you need to dispatch the action like this:

```
store.dispatch(selectUser());
```

That way the action will get to the reducer, your reducer will get updated and then your component will receive the new data.

You can get the store from the context, however... you can also use the function you already binded it inside `matchDispatchToProps`, in order to do that you need to do something like this:

```
createListItems() {
    const selectUserBinded = this.props.selectUser; // <----

    return this.props.users.map((user) => {
        return (    
            <View key={user.id}> 
                <Button onPress={function(){return selectUserBinded(user);}}>
                    <Text>{user.first} {user.last}</Text>
                    <Icon  style={styles.TextLight} name='arrow-forward' android="md-arrow-forward"/>
                </Button>
            </View>
            );
        });
}
```

And that function will automatically run your action creator using the `dispatch` from the store.

Notice that `this.props.selectUser !== selectUser`!! `this.props.selectUser` is already binded to the store while `selectUser` is not.

*EDIT*
Try to bind your actions like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users,
        user: state.activeUser 
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { selectUser: selectUser })(UserList);
```

That looks a lot more clean and easier to understand, the second parameter `{ selectUser: selectUser }` is just an object with the methods to bind, no need to define verbose functions to do the binding, just a simple object. If using ES6, you can just do `{ selectUser }`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I created the selectUserBinded Const and included it in the OnPress function. But, I'm not sure where I should include the - store.dispatch(selectUser()); you suggested. Here is a link to the repo incase this will help https://github.com/psychatelli/ReactNativeApp

Comment: Also, when I created the selectUserBinded Const and connect it to the button, I click the button and receive the error "Actions may not have an undefined "Type" property. Have you misspelled a constant".  This error may be happening as a result of not using the   store.dispatch(selectUser());  .  Not sure where to include this.

Comment: You don't need to include `store.dispatch(selectUser());` that was an explanation of what's happening under the hood ;)

Comment: @AdamDonatelli I've edited my answer, take a look at how you need to bind the actions, hope that solves your issue

Comment: I deffinately think your on to something, but I'm still receiving this error with the edits you suggested: "Actions may not have an undefined "Type" property. Have you misspelled a constant".

Comment: Make sure your import is correct: `import USER_SELECTED from './types';`. The errors is telling you `USER_SELECTED` is undefined ;) you might be missing the `{}` => `import { USER_SELECTED } from './types'`

Comment: All is spelled correctly.  Not sure why this error is happening.

Comment: Show your `./types` file, maybe the export is wrong?

Comment: This is the only line in my types file:   export const USER_SELECTED = "USER_SELECTED";

Comment: did you added the `{}` to the import? Otherwise it will not import your constant correctly, it should be like this: `import { USER_SELECTED } from './types'`

Comment: Nice!  That got rid of the error. But... The component still isn't rendering the Props.  I think we are so close here.

Comment: This is what I have in my Main App.js file:   https://jsfiddle.net/psychatelli/j7bdhdno/

Comment: This is the code I have within the App.js file located within my Src file   https://jsfiddle.net/psychatelli/7e5pLwh9/1/

Comment: In the description of my original question, I've made an edited and provided another set of code. I've included my code from my Index.js file within my reducer file.  If you look at my component, I created a variable like this  'user: state.activeUser' located in my MapStateToProps function.  Perhaps this variable is not communicating with the index file located in my reducer folder??